How to redirect to moodle page (Moodle 4.5) from external site without showing login page
I have an external site developed in .net having OpenID SSO enabled and a moodle site using the same SSO. The user want to click a link in external site to a specific page in moodle. But the login page appears when user click the link. How can we navigate the user to requested page without showing login page. I am pretty new to Moodle. Using the version 4.5.
I am a dot net developer. I don't have much knowledge in PHP.
Any help will be appreciated.

If i remember correctly you can generate a token in your admin dashboard an use it execute a passwordless login calling the endpoint, this link can be a good start point https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=193857

Hi @JDarwind, Thank you for your reply. I went through some suggestions and one of them was OAuth2 will help to achieve this. I had set up OAuth2 in my moodle site and I am able to login with OAuth2. Then I tried to access moodle page from external site. But still same issue.  Any suggestion on this.

If you turn on the Silent login option in the OpenID Connect settings, any user that already has a token from the same IDP used for OIDC on their Web Browser will be automatically logged in and sent back to the link used to enter Moodle. This setting is under Other options and requires Forced redirect (/admin/settings.php?section=authsettingoidc) and Force users to login (/admin/settings.php?section=sitepolicies).
If they don't have the necessary token on their Web Browser yet, the IDP's login will appear. That said, once they logged in for the first time, they won't have too the next, provided they use the same Web Browser and don't clear their cache/use private browsing or incognito mode.

+10000 votes...It is working like charm. Thank you very much

One more help. Is that possible to logout from Moodle if user logout from External site? same SSO scenario. I have configured single Sign out (from Moodle to IdP and it is working fine). But reverse is not working.

Hi again, I wouldn't know how it works with the External site. If they have a similar option that Moodle offers, perhaps. One think to keep in mind is that once authenticated on Moodle through the SSO, the session remains available until it expires, with or without a valid SSO token. Therefore, if a user has logged on Moodle and logs off from your External site, it may not log them off Moodle until their session expires. Session handling on Moodle is under /admin/settings.php?section=sessionhandling. Cheers!

Thank you for your reply.  I found an option in moodle itself and trying it now. Will let you know if it work.  "Front-channel Logout URL : This is the URL that your IdP needs to trigger when it tries to log users out of Moodle. ".

I tried to include Front-channel Logout URL in appsettings. But looks it is not working. But while going through some documentations I could see below configuration  in appsettings .
"BackChannelLogoutSessionRequired": true,
"BackChannelLogoutUri": "/auth/oidc/logout.php",
"RequirePkce": false,
Here my doubt is, when I changed RequirePkce to true,  moodle site started failing. I am not sure why it is happening. Any idea how we can enable PKCE in moodle.
